# PHP Convert stdClass Object to array and group by Value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key-value

I'm working on a multidimensional array. How can i group it by value ? In the following array [0][1] have same group_id. In this case i want to group these together.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 142
            [city_name] => Abhayapuri
            [state_id] => 4
            [group_id] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 494
            [city_name] => Achabbal
            [state_id] => 15
            [group_id] => 2
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1302
            [city_name] => Achhnera
            [state_id] => 34
            [group_id] => 1
        )
)
```

Is there any way to achieve it.

Comment: Iterate over the array and put each object inside another array that corresponds to its group id. Did you try something like that?

Comment: @Jon I've tried but all i'm getting is **Cannot use object of type stdClass as array**